# Python Pandas repeat the same number every 12 rows

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create 'Year' column, that repeats the value of every year every 12 rows starting from 2000 to 2018 like below:

```
1   2000
2   2000
3   2000
4   2000
5   2000
6   2000
7   2000
8   2000
9   2000
10  2000
11  2000
12  2000
1   2001
2   2001
3   2001
4   2001
5   2001
6   2001
7   2001
8   2001
9   2001
10  2001
11  2001
12  2001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [year for year in range(2000, 2019)]})
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(12)]
```

You can also reset the index:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(12)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
for year in range(2000, 2019):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        print(month, "\t", year)
```

Output:

```
1    2000
2    2000
3    2000
4    2000
5    2000

...
...
...

7    2018
8    2018
9    2018
10   2018
11   2018
12   2018
```

Comment: judging by the title of this thread, I suspect he means pandas dataframe column

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the following:

```
Year = []
for i in range(12*19):
    Year.append(2000+int(i/12))
print(Year)
```

It returns `[2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018]`